# 3D-accelerated Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, hardware-acceleration

How can I get Flash to be 3D-accelerated for a computer with a powerful discrete graphics card? Is there any specific version of Flash required or specific configuration for it?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/q/91932/3256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with what danjil [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58960/3d-accelerated-adobe-flash/58962#58962); you need to ensure that your card is supported. Unfortunately, up to know flash only supports HW acceleration on nVidia cards, and then only with supported drivers (they must support the vdpau acceleration API).

If you are using ATI graphics, or Open Source drivers for any card that does not support this API, you will probably not get hardware acceleration even in Flash 11.

However, Adobe has said in the past that they have plans for supporting VA-API as well, so hopefully the wait should soon be over.

Comment: _NVGTX460_ burned already on playing massive flash  ...
display failed to black screen with 1 and 3 beeps. Unlucky year begin. Warning!

Answer (score 3):

Flash 9.0.115.0 brought 3D hardware acceleration to Linux. Due to a series of [problems](http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2008/05/flash_uses_the_gpu.html) using 3D acceleration, the feature is not enabled by default.

To enable 3D acceleration you have to set **OverrideGPUValidation** to `true`.

You can either do this in:

- `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` (you might need to create the folder) for a system wide change
- `~/.adobe/mms.cfg` for a user change

See here: http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2008/08/secrets_of_the_mmscfg_file_1.html