# Is Adobe Flash 11.2 working with Nvidia hardware again?

Tags: nvidia, flash, hardware-acceleration

I installed the newest Nvidia-Linux drivers version number 304.43 on 12.04 installation and all Flash Videos now show me "**accelerated video rendering**".

Previous Nvidia drivers + Adobe Flash only rendered in software, at least since Adobe officially said they turned off "**hardware acceleration**" for Linux, because of unstable and unsecure drivers.

Has this changed? Is hardware acceleration really back? Can anyone verify this as well?

The Nvidia driver 304.43 patch notes said:

> Fixed a bug that caused VDPAU to hang when expanding the YouTube Flash Player.

Hardware: Nvidia 8600M GT

Answer (score 3):

Mandriva 2010.2 i586
flash 11.2.232.238

the blue tint pb was fixed by nvidia since 304.37 if you read the release note

i have no more blue tint pb with flash  since i have 304.37

there is acceleration for rendering but no hw accel for decoding

acceleration for rendering is not hw accel. if i understand well it is just that flash use xrender (<=>direct tech for windows)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest Nvidia and Flash 11.2 and the smurf effect is still there in YouTube videos when using hardware acceleration, but, I have noticed that using Google Chrome and it's built in PepperFlash 11.3, fixes the problem completely.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you for your feedback! :) With Chrome we now have Smurf-free video and working hardware acceleration (at least "accelerated video rendering"). Can anyone else confirm this as well? This would be awesome - especially for ION/Nvidia based Netbooks or smaller computers.